# INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE when using CreateFile(”\\.\C:“,...)

Tags: windows, winapi

the code is here

```
HANDLE hDrive = CreateFile(_T("\\\\.\\D:"), GENERIC_READ, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 
    NULL, 
    OPEN_ALWAYS, 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,///*FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH |*/FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 
    NULL);
assert(hDrive != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
```

I also tried `CreateFile(_T("\\\.\D:",...)` and `OPEN_EXISTING`, but also return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

I called `GetLastError()`, and the error code is 5, `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: Have you looked at the result of GetLastError() to determine the associated error code?

Comment: Thank you , I will take a look

Comment: Try `\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1:` instead of `\\\\.\\D:` or it might be `PhysicalDrive0` depending on how drives are mapped. ps also `OPEN_EXISTING` as pointed out earlier.

Comment: The program must run elevated in order to get raw access to a drive.  UAC elevation required, edit the program's manifest to display the prompt.

Comment: The best quick lookup for error codes is to simply search for the number in <winerror.h>. In this case, 5 is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED which correlates strongly with Hans Passant's analysis.

Comment: @ChrisBecke: That's probably the worst way to look up error codes. Other methods, that are arguably easier and - most of all - more reliable include: `1` Enter the value in the VS Error Lookup tool (*Tools* -> *Error Lookup*). `2` Enter the value in VS' watch window with the `,hr` format specifier, i.e. `5,hr`. `3` Open a command prompt and have *net helpmsg* perform the lookup for you, i.e. `net helpmsg 5`.

Comment: `4` Browser through the list of [System Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to @Barmak Shemirani and @Hans Passant,

I got a workable code

```
HANDLE hDrive = CreateFile(_T("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"), GENERIC_READ, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 
    NULL, 
    OPEN_EXISTING, 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY,///*FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH |*/FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 
    NULL);
```

and

```
HANDLE hDrive = CreateFile(_T("\\\\.\\D:"), GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 
    NULL, 
    OPEN_EXISTING, 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY,///*FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH |*/FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 
    NULL);
DWORD dwError = GetLastError();

assert(hDrive != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
cin.get();
```

need to run as administrator

Comment: Actually `"\\\\.\\D:"` might work too, the problem is that `d:` could be either a disk or partition. Also if you just want to get disk information, try replacing `GENERIC_READ` with `0`, see if it runs without elevated access.

Comment: thanks a lot :),i tried,it also need to run as administrator